# Capistrano rollback broken Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting ")")

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

I've got a rails 3.2 app which deploys fine with Capistrano, the other day though I wanted to rollback and I couldn't do this as I got the following error;

```
$ cap staging deploy:rollback
    triggering load callbacks
  * 2014-12-04 13:34:43 executing `staging'
    triggering start callbacks for `deploy:rollback'
  * 2014-12-04 13:34:43 executing `multistage:ensure'
    triggering after callbacks for `multistage:ensure'
  * 2014-12-04 13:34:43 executing `rbenv:setup_default_environment'
  * 2014-12-04 13:34:43 executing `deploy:rollback'
  * 2014-12-04 13:34:43 executing `deploy:rollback:revision'
  * executing "ls -x /srv/pais/releases"
    servers: ["staging.pais.com.au"]
    [staging.pais.com.au] executing command
    command finished in 38ms
  * executing "rm /srv/pais/current;  ln -s /srv/pais/releases/20141203050547 /srv/pais/current"
    servers: ["staging.pais.com.au"]
    [staging.pais.com.au] executing command
    command finished in 10ms
    triggering after callbacks for `deploy:rollback:revision'
  * 2014-12-04 13:34:43 executing `deploy:assets:rollback'
  * executing "ls /srv/pais/releases/20141203050547/assets_manifest.*"
    servers: ["staging.pais.com.au"]
    [staging.pais.com.au] executing command
    command finished in 13ms
  * executing "[ -e /srv/pais/releases/20141203050547/assets_manifest.yml ] && echo true || echo false"
    servers: ["staging.pais.com.au"]
    [staging.pais.com.au] executing command
    command finished in 8ms
  * executing "ls /srv/pais/shared/assets/manifest*"
    servers: ["staging.pais.com.au"]
    [staging.pais.com.au] executing command
    command finished in 13ms
  * executing "cd -- /srv/pais/releases/20141203050547 && cp -f -- /srv/pais/releases/20141203050547/assets_manifest.yml /srv/pais/shared/assets/manifest.yml && [ -z \"$(#<Capistrano::Configuration::Namespaces::Namespace:0x007fa9e9413530> -P | grep assets:precompile:nondigest)\" ] || #<Capistrano::Configuration::Namespaces::Namespace:0x007fa9e9413530> RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile:nondigest"
    servers: ["staging.pais.com.au"]
    [staging.pais.com.au] executing command
 ** [out :: staging.pais.com.au] sh: 1:
 ** [out :: staging.pais.com.au] Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting ")")
 ** [out :: staging.pais.com.au] 
    command finished in 9ms
failed: "env RBENV_ROOT=/usr/local/rbenv PATH=/usr/local/rbenv/shims:/usr/local/rbenv/bin:$PATH sh -c 'cd -- /srv/pais/releases/20141203050547 && cp -f -- /srv/pais/releases/20141203050547/assets_manifest.yml /srv/pais/shared/assets/manifest.yml && [ -z \"$(#<Capistrano::Configuration::Namespaces::Namespace:0x007fa9e9413530> -P | grep assets:precompile:nondigest)\" ] || #<Capistrano::Configuration::Namespaces::Namespace:0x007fa9e9413530> RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile:nondigest'" on staging.pais.com.au
```

I'm using capistrano version 2.15.5 and deploying from & to a Debian 7 machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was I had the following in my deploy.rb

```
namespace :rake
```

I changed this to

```
namespace :raketask
```

Comment: Soooo cryptic! I had the exact same issue. Thank you for this :)

Comment: I had the same issue too.